# Проблема со стандартным вводом-выводом СPP

Tags: c++, cin, stdin

В чем может быть проблема? Системная или все-таки с кодом? Вродебы ошибок в коде нет, но система не реагирует на нажатие "Enter" при вводе с помощью cin. Код написан в qt, система сборки  qmake.
Общий код - простейший:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <QDebug>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  
    int matrix[100][100];
    int rows;
    int collumns;

    cout << "Cuantos rows queres: ";
    cin >> rows;
    cout << rows;
    return a.exec(); 
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте убрать QCoreApplication и a.exec().

Comment: Или добавьте `cout << rows << endl;`

Comment: проблема не в cout, а в cin. Тем не менне - попытался заменить, проблема осталась. Комментирование вызова core в qt не помогла. Проблема сохраняется

Comment: А какое поведение ожидается? И что вы видите фактически? Я полагаю, что вы ввели число rows, ожидаете его немедленного вывода и завершения программы. А наблюдаете то, что вы ввели число, нажали enter  и ничего не происходит. Верно? Вместо `return a.exec();` напишите `return 0`. Или подробнее опишите ожидаемое и наблюдаемое поведение.

Comment: Вы правы, после нажатия клавиши enter ожидается запись в переменную с выводом значения. Однако нажатие enter не завершает выполнение функции cin в результате чего программа не продолжает свое функционирование ( не производит вывод приведенного значения второй командой cout ), ожидая дальнейшего ввода значения.

Comment: изменение на return 0 - не решило проблему

Comment: Странно... Попробовал запустить Ваш код. Если оставить на месте QCoreApplication, приложение возвращает введенное число и виснет. Если убрать, то выводит и завершается.

Comment: То есть ввели число, нажали enter, но в это время программа продолжает принимать ввод? То есть можно продолжать печатать символы?

Comment: Да, именно так. Также нажатие enter работает как перевод строки, т.е. символ '\n'

Comment: У вас нет никаких надстроек над консолью? Какая ОС?

Comment: стандартная manjaro последней версии. qt - v 5.15, надстроек нет. Все пакеты обновлены до последних доступных версий.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить исполняемый файл отдельно от среды разработки (или в терминале). Для этого может понадобиться добавить пути к библиотекам Qt в переменную окружения Path.

Comment: @arrr, *maestro* тебе уже правильно изначально сказал: добавь `<< endl` и будет вывод: потоки вывода буферизируются... а если дальнейшая работа после ввода не нужна, то убери `a.exec()`...

Answer (score 2):

Это не ответ на вопрос, но тем не менее я хочу объяснить, почему я дал такие советы в комментариях.

Что такое `QCoreApplication`? Это особый объект, который создаёт и запускает очередь событий - `QEventLoop`. Очередь событий нужна для обработки внутренних потребностей Qt, в том числе обслуживания механизма сигналов и слотов. Строка

```
return a.exec();
```

запускает очередь событий, и будет выполняться до тех пор, пока вы не вызовете `a.quit()`. То есть ваша программа не завершится никогда (нажатие крестика закрытия консоли - это аварийное завершение, фактически - убийство процесса).

Если ваша программа представляет собой линейный однопоточный алгоритм, то `QEventLoop` и, соответственно, `QCoreApplication` вам не нужны. В конце функции main можно написать `return 0;`.

Теперь про оператор вывода. При помещении данных в поток вывода `cout` эти данные буферизуются, и могут фактически появиться в устройстве вывода (консоли) не тогда, когда вы вызвали оператор `<<`. Буфер может сбрасываться при вызове метода `cout.flush()`, при помещении в поток объекта `std::endl`, при вызове деструктора потока (например, при завершении работы программы). При убийстве процесса буфер не сбрасывается. Поскольку ваша программа никогда не завершается, то и сброса буфера нет, следовательно, введённые данные не попадут обратно в вывод.

Теперь вы утверждаете, что вызов оператора `>>` для потока `cin` не завершается, и вы определили это по тому признаку, что после нажатия клавиши enter программа продолжает читать поток. Я думаю, это поведение какого-то нестандартного терминала, и советую вам попробовать запустить программу в чистой среде. Например, без использования среды разработки. Или в другой операционной системе. Если там будет всё хорошо, то искать проблему в вашем терминале.